# Break the google chart legend labels

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

in google api chart am trying to modify the legend of my chart.

Here am trying to display the legend labels by putting a br tag like this ReleaseVersion
3 and want to display in UI as one by one

```
Version
3
```

In code i tried in following ways but no hope

```
data.addColumn('number', 'Version<br>2');
data.addColumn('number', 'Version'+document.write('<br/>')+'3');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Version'+ document.createElement("br")+' 3');
```

How can i split the label text using br tag or any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the legend labels will not accept html

but you can use the line break character --> `\n`

```
  data.addColumn('number', 'ReleaseVersion\n3.21.50');
```

see following working snippet...

note: may need to adjust the `chartArea`, to allow enough room for the labels...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'ReleaseVersion\n3.21.48');
  data.addColumn('number', 'ReleaseVersion\n3.21.49');
  data.addColumn('number', 'ReleaseVersion\n3.21.50');
  data.addRows([
    ['1', 2, 1, 3],
    ['2', 2, 1, 1],
    ['3', 1, 2, 4],
    ['4', 0, 3, 0]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 24,
      height: '100%',
      left: 48,
      right: 200,
      top: 24,
      width: '100%'
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      position: 'right'
    },
    title: 'Title',
    width: '100%'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this for data labels (not legend labels) and it wouldn't work, the graph does not render at all... :-(